# boost::asio::ioservice threadpool is running all code on the same thread ID

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost

I am using `boost::asio::ioservice` to create a threadpool with 100 threads.

In a while loop I want to post 5 threads to do this work:

```
void dowork(int i) {
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    cout << " thread ID :" << boost::this_thread::get_id();
}
```

Then I do `work.reset()`.

Despite the threadpool size being 100, at posting time it didn't take the 5 threads.  In fact, when I print the thread ID it is the same for all 5 threads.

So it's not executing in parallel...why is that?

```
int main() {
    int ch;
    int i;
    boost::asio::io_service ioservice;
    boost::thread_group threadpool;

    auto_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work(
         new boost::asio::io_service::work(ioservice)
    );

    for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
        threadpool.create_thread(
            boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioservice)
        );
    }

    ch=0;
    while(ch <= 5) {
        ch++;
        cout << "in main" << boost::this_thread::get_id() << endl;
        for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
            ioservice.post(boost::bind(dowork,10));
        }
        std::cout << "size=" << threadpool.size() <<std::endl;
        work.reset();
        ioservice.reset();
        ioservice.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: please edit that wall of text to be more readable

Comment: you are not actually passing any messages the the threads, I think you need to go back to the documentation

Comment: @imran Several people have edited your question.  I upvoted it from negative, because if it had been written like the final version to start with it would've been fine.  Yet please [notice the changes](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24710187/revisions) and focus on how you might ask clear questions to start with.  [This guide to MarkDown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) should be helpful; try to ensure the preview is legible before posting.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, the first batch of tasks **is** executed on all threads of the "pool". See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e64841198c791a82)**

However, at the end of the loop, you reset the work. This causes all the threads to exit **[¹]**. It's no surprise that your main thread will be the sole handling thread for subsequent tasks posted.

I'd suggest not making the main thread invoke `run()` there at all. Also, using 100 threads is a (big) anti-pattern. It's unusual for so many workers to make any sense.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::atomic_int tid_gen(0);

void dowork(int i) {
    thread_local int tid = ++tid_gen;
    std::cout << "hello";
    std::cout << " thread ID :" << tid << "\n";
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service ioservice;
    boost::thread_group group;

    boost::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work> work(boost::asio::io_service::work{ioservice});

    for(size_t i=0; i<boost::thread::hardware_concurrency(); i++) {
        group.create_thread(
            boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioservice)
        );
    }

    std::cout << "in main thread size=" << group.size() <<std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i <= 5; ++i) {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            ioservice.post(boost::bind(dowork,10));
        }

        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(600));
        std::cout << "waking up\n";
    }

    work.reset(); // allow threads to exit
    group.join_all(); // await proper thread shutdown
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/339a8c0373d33ec4)**

---

**[¹]**. (In fact, if you didn't, the threads would still run at program exit, leading to undefined behaviour).